# Plotting Pandas DataFrame from pivot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot

I am trying to plot a line graph comparing the Murder Rates of particular States through the years 1960-1962 using Pandas in a Jupyter Notebook.

A little context about where I am now, and how I arrived here:

I'm using a crime csv file, which looks like this:
[image]

I'm only interested in 3 columns for the time being: State, Year, and Murder Rate. Specifically I was interested in only 5 states - Alaska, Michigan, Minnesota, Maine, Wisconsin.

So to produce the desired table, I did this (only showing top 5 row entries):

```
al_mi_mn_me_wi = crimes[(crimes['State'] == 'Alaska') | (crimes['State'] =='Michigan') | (crimes['State'] =='Minnesota') | (crimes['State'] =='Maine') | (crimes['State'] =='Wisconsin')]
control_df = al_mi_mn_me_wi[['State', 'Year', 'Murder Rate']]
```

[image]

From here I used the **pivot** function

```
df = control_1960_to_1962.pivot(index = 'Year', columns = 'State',values= 'Murder Rate' )
```

[image]

And this is where I get stuck. I received KeyError when doing (KeyError was Year):

```
df.plot(x='Year', y='Murder Rate', kind='line')
```

and when attempting just

```
df.plot()
```

I get this wonky graph.

[image]

How do I get my desired graph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a dataframe in a long (tidy) format, `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` is used to transform to a wide format, which can be plotted directly with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

**Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

control_1960_to_1962 = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': np.repeat(['Alaska', 'Maine', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Wisconsin'], 3),
    'Year': [1960, 1961, 1962]*5,
    'Murder Rate': [10.2, 11.5, 4.5, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4, 4.5, 4.1, 3.4, 1.2, 1.0, .9, 1.3, 1.6, .9]
})

df = control_1960_to_1962.pivot(index='Year', columns='State', values='Murder Rate')

# display(df)
State  Alaska  Maine  Michigan  Minnesota  Wisconsin
Year                                                
1960     10.2    1.7       4.5        1.2        1.3
1961     11.5    1.6       4.1        1.0        1.6
1962      4.5    1.4       3.4        0.9        0.9
```

## The plots

You can tell Pandas (and through it the `matplotlib` package that actually does the plotting) what xticks you want explicitly:

```
ax = df.plot(xticks=df.index, ylabel='Murder Rate')
```

Output:

[image]

`ax` is a [`matplotlib.axes.Axes` object](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), and there are many, many customizations you can make to your plot through it.

Here's how to plot with the `States` on the x axis:

```
ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Murder Rate')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this you can explore more

```
   pip install pivottablejs

   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
   df = pd.DataFrame({
      'State': np.repeat(['Alaska', 'Maine', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota','Wisconsin'], 3),
      'Year': [1960, 1961, 1962]*5,
      'Murder Rate': [10.2, 11.5, 4.5, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4, 4.5, 4.1, 3.4, 1.2, 1.0, .9, 1.3, 1.6, .9]})
```

pivot_ui(df)

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting, can you tell me more about what the cell values 1 and 2 signify in this case?

Edit: Is it the count of which states have those specified murder rates?

Comment: This has not been updated for the last four years.Check before use, https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable