# unexpected result with pandas plot

Tags: pandas, plot

I have  a dataframe as below:

```
      year  hour  system_load
0     2013     0     23
1     2013     1     22
2     2013     2     22
3     2013     3     21
4     2013     4     19
..     ...   ...   ...     
187   2020    19     30
188   2020    20     29
189   2020    21     28
190   2020    22     28
191   2020    23     28
```

I am trying to plot by the following code:

```
dff.plot(x='hour',y='system_load')
```

The result as follows:
[image: the picture below is distorted by unexpected lines]

What I want is removing these lines between start and end of the curve each year and refers to each curve by its year and finally plot each curve with different color.

Comment: Can you provide your data in the form of a dictionary or pandas dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting Pandas DataFrame from Pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811565/plotting-pandas-dataframe-from-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot your data.

```
dff.pivot(index='hour', columns='year', values='system_load').plot()
```